# How can I merge resource files in a Maven assembly?

Tags: maven-2, assemblies, build-automation

I'm using Maven and its assembly plugin to build a distribution package of my project like this:

- one project assembles a basic runtime (based on Felix), with the appropriate directories and bundles, in a ZIP file.
- third-party libraries are collected in one project each and either converted to OSGi bundles or, if they are already OSGi compatible, they are just copied
- my own project consists of several modules that are built into OSGi bundles, too.

Now, I'm adding another project that unpacks the ZIP, drops all the other JARs into the proper directories, and repackages it for distribution. Now, my bundles might contain configuration files that I want to merge into, rather than replacing, identically named ones in the runtime assembly. How do I do that?

The files are plain text (property files), but I might run into a similar situation with XML files later.

Comment: I don't know anything that can do this. That said, I'm not very used to OSGI. However, is this a "regular" use case?

Comment: @Pascal - This is not specific to OSGi, really. I'm not sure how regular this is, but I could imagine that if I wanted to merge WARs or OSGi bundles, I might want to merge web.xml or MANIFEST.MF files, respectively. I'm sure there is other tasks of the same type, but maybe there's a completely different approach to this.

Comment: Why merging OSGI bundles? I'm a big noob with OSGI but aren't they independent units? For WARs, it's a little bit more clear but I can think of many issues with a merge (e.g. what if both wars have an `index.jsp`, what if they both rely on the same lib but with different versions, etc) and would rather consider them as independent units too. Patching a `web.xml` seems more "realist" (and can be useful, e.g. in a testing context, cargo has a goal for that).

Comment: @Pascal - don't get too hung up on those examples. The use case for the plugin I was pointed to in the accepted answer is actually quite sound.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know of a robust solution to this problem. But a bit of looking around shows that somebody has [created a plugin](http://beardedgeeks.googlecode.com/svn/docs/maven-merge-properties-plugin/0.2/index.html) to merge properties files. By the look of it you need to tell it which files to merge, which is a good thing as you don't want this applied willy nilly.

Assuming you have used dependency-unpack to unpack the zip to a known location, it would be a case of configuring the plugin to merge each pair of properties files and specify the appropriate target location.

You could extend the plugin to handle XML by using something like xmlmerge from EL4J, as described in [this Javaworld article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-07-2007/jw-07-xmlmerge.html).

Comment: The plugin is actually made by me. Nice to see it has become useful for someone.

Comment: the link broke again

Comment: The current link is https://github.com/code-troopers/merge-properties-maven-plugin

Answer (score 27):

Expanding a bit on Juergen's answer for those who stumble on this - the `containerDescriptorHandler` in the descriptor can take four values (v2.3), these are `metaInf-services`, `file-aggregator`, `plexus`, `metaInf-spring`. It's a bit buried in the code (found in the package `org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.filter`) but it is possible to aggregate config/properties files.

Here's an example descriptor that aggregates the `META-INF/services` and
named property files located in `com.mycompany.actions`.

**descriptor.xml**

```
<assembly>

...

<containerDescriptorHandlers>

    <containerDescriptorHandler>
        <handlerName>metaInf-services</handlerName>
    </containerDescriptorHandler>

    <containerDescriptorHandler>
        <handlerName>file-aggregator</handlerName>
        <configuration>
            <filePattern>com/mycompany/actions/action.properties</filePattern>
            <outputPath>com/mycompany/actions/action.properties</outputPath>
        </configuration>
    </containerDescriptorHandler>

</containerDescriptorHandlers>

....

</assembly>
```

The `file-aggregator` can contain a regular expression in the `filePattern` to match multiple files. The following would match all files names 'action.properties'.

```
<filePattern>.+/action.properties</filePattern>
```

The `metaInf-services` and `metaInf-spring` are used for aggregating [SPI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/SPI-intro.html) and spring config files respectively whilst the `plexus` handler will aggregate `META-INF/plexus/components.xml` together.

If you need something more specialised you can add your own configuration handler by implementing `ContainerDescriptorHandler` and defining the component in `META-INF/plexus/components.xml`. You can do this by creating an upstream project which has a dependency on `maven-assembly-plugin` and contains your custom handler.  It might be possible to do this in the same project you're assembling but I didn't try that. Implementations of the handlers can be found in `org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.filter.*` package of the assembly source code.

**CustomHandler.java**

```
package com.mycompany;

import org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.filter.ContainerDescriptorHandler;

public class CustomHandler implements ContainerDescriptorHandler {
    // body not shown
}
```

then define the component in `/src/main/resources/META-INF/plexus/components.xml`

**components.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<component-set>
    <components>
        <component>
            <role>org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.filter.ContainerDescriptorHandler</role>
            <role-hint>custom-handler</role-hint>
            <implementation>com.mycompany.CustomHandler</implementation>
            <instantiation-strategy>per-lookup</instantiation-strategy>
        </component>
    </components>
</component-set>
```

Finally you add this as a dependency on the assembly plugin in the project you wish to assemble

**pom.xml**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <descriptors>
            <descriptor>...</descriptor>
        </descriptors>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
            <artifactId>sample-handler</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

and define the handlerName in the descriptor

**descriptor.xml**

```
...
<containerDescriptorHandler>
    <handlerName>custom-handler</handlerName>
</containerDescriptorHandler>
...
```

The [maven-shade-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) can also create 'uber-jars' and has some resource transforms for handling XML, licences and manifests.

J

Comment: All that just to specify `metaInf-services`? I don't need or want a `descriptor.xml` file. Is there any way to simply indicate the `metaInf-services` handler in the `<plugin><configuration>` in the POM>

Comment: For reference, I think the Assemble plugin docs have caught up - https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/single/using-container-descriptor-handlers.html

Answer (score 10):

Old question but stumbled over it while trying to solve similar problem: Assembly plugin 2.2 has capabilities to merge files: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_containerDescriptorHandler
e.g. handlerName "metaInf-services" (will concat all META-INF/services files), "metaInf-spring" are the only ones I know of (I personally needed metaInf-services)

Answer (score 1):

Ive also created a merge files plugin, in my case i use it to merge SQL files from various projects into a single installer SQL file which can create all the schemas/tables/static data etc for our apps in a single file, http://croche.googlecode.com/svn/docs/maven-merge-files-plugin/0.1/usage.html

Comment: Why I see http://croche.googlecode.com/svn/docs/maven-merge-files-plugin/0.4/usage.html as a plain text and not HTML?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/rob19780114/merge-maven-plugin (available on maven central) also seems to do the job.
See below for an example configuration

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.zcore.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>merge-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>merge</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>merge</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <mergers>
                <merger>
                  <target>${build.outputDirectory}/output-file-1</target>
                  <sources>
                    <source>src/main/resources/file1</source>
                    <source>src/main/resources/file2</source>
                  </sources>
                </merger>
                <merger>
                  <target>${build.outputDirectory}/output-file-2</target>
                  <sources>
                    <source>src/main/resources/file3</source>
                    <source>src/main/resources/file4</source>
                  </sources>
                </merger>
              </mergers>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
```

Comment: this plugin is too slow