# Jersey error JAXBStringReaderProviders$RootElementProvider

Tags: java, jersey, jetty

> 17-53-2014 12:53:31.817 INFO  - Registering com.citronium.fizionomizm.service.server.controllers.Root as a root resource class 
>   17-53-2014 12:53:31.820 INFO  - Registering com.citronium.fizionomizm.service.server.controllers.RecognizePath as a root resource class 
>   17-53-2014 12:53:31.822 INFO  - Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.18 11/22/2013 03:05 AM' 
>   17-53-2014 12:53:31.929 ERROR - The provider class, class com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.parameter.multivalued.JAXBStringReaderProviders$RootElementProvider, could not be instantiated. Processing will continue but the class will not be utilized 
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
>       at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.*getInstance(ComponentConstructor.java:210) ~[fizionomizm-service.jar:0.1]
>       at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.getInstance(ComponentConstructor.java:180) ~[fizionomizm-service.jar:0.1]
>       at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.*_getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:166) [fizionomizm-service.jar:0.1]
>       at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:137) [fizionomizm-service.jar:0.1]
>       at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getComponent(ProviderServices.java:283) [fizionomizm-service.jar:0.1]
>       at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getProvidersAndServices(ProviderServices.java:176) [fizionomizm-service.jar:0.1]
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.parameter.multivalued.StringReaderFactory.init(StringReaderFactory.java:60) [fizionomizm-service.jar:0.1]
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1341) [fizionomizm-service.jar:0.1]
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180) [fizionomizm-service.jar:0.1]
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799) [fizionomizm-service.jar:0.1]
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795) [fizionomizm-service.jar:0.1]
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193) [fizionomizm-service.jar:0.1]
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795) [fizionomizm-service.jar:0.1]
>       at com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.servlet.GuiceContainer.initiate(GuiceContainer.java:121) [fizionomizm-service.jar:0.1]
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:321) [fizionomizm-service.jar:0.1]
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605) [fizionomizm-service.jar:0.1]
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207) [fizionomizm-service.jar:0.1]
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:376) [fizionomizm-service.jar:0.1]
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:559) [fizionomizm-service.jar:0.1]
>       at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244) [fizionomizm-service.jar:0.1]
>       at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.init(ServletDefinition.java:119) [fizionomizm-service.jar:0.1]
>       at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.init(ManagedServletPipeline.java:84) [fizionomizm-service.jar:0.1]
>       at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.initPipeline(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:104) [fizionomizm-service.jar:0.1]
>       at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.init(GuiceFilter.java:224) [fizionomizm-service.jar:0.1]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.initialize(FilterHolder.java:137) [fizionomizm-service.jar:0.1]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:810) [fizionomizm-service.jar:0.1]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:288) [fizionomizm-service.jar:0.1]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:743) [fizionomizm-service.jar:0.1]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69) [fizionomizm-service.jar:0.1]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117) [fizionomizm-service.jar:0.1]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:355) [fizionomizm-service.jar:0.1]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:99) [fizionomizm-service.jar:0.1]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60) [fizionomizm-service.jar:0.1]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:324) [fizionomizm-service.jar:0.1]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69) [fizionomizm-service.jar:0.1]
>       at com.citronium.fizionomizm.service.server.restserver.RESTServer.start(RESTServer.java:68) [fizionomizm-service.jar:0.1]
>       at com.citronium.fizionomizm.service.Runner.main(Runner.java:19) [fizionomizm-service.jar:0.1]
>   17-53-2014 12:53:32.235 INFO  - Binding com.citronium.fizionomizm.service.server.controllers.Root to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "Singleton" 
>   17-53-2014 12:53:32.249 INFO  - Binding com.citronium.fizionomizm.service.server.controllers.RecognizePath to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "Singleton" 
>   17-53-2014 12:53:32.365 ERROR - The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
>     SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.parameter.multivalued.JAXBStringReaderProviders$RootElementProvider(com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable,javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers) at parameter index 0
>     SEVERE: Method, public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.citronium.fizionomizm.service.server.controllers.RecognizePath.upload(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.io.IOException, annotated with POST of resource, class com.citronium.fizionomizm.service.server.controllers.RecognizePath, is not recognized as valid resource method.
>     SEVERE: Method, public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.citronium.fizionomizm.service.server.controllers.RecognizePath.analyse(java.lang.String,java.lang.String), annotated with PUT of resource, class com.citronium.fizionomizm.service.server.controllers.RecognizePath, is not recognized as valid resource method.
>     SEVERE: Method, public synchronized javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.sun.jersey.server.impl.wadl.WadlResource.geExternalGramar(javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo,java.lang.String), annotated with GET of resource, class com.sun.jersey.server.impl.wadl.WadlResource, is not recognized as valid resource method.
>     SEVERE: Method, public synchronized javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.sun.jersey.server.impl.wadl.WadlResource.getWadl(javax.ws.rs.core.Request,javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo,javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers), annotated with GET of resource, class com.sun.jersey.server.impl.wadl.WadlResource, is not recognized as valid resource method. 
>   17-53-2014 12:53:32.375 ERROR - Error while start server. 
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
>       at com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.servlet.GuiceContainer.initiate(GuiceContainer.java:121)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:321)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:376)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:559)
>       at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
>       at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.init(ServletDefinition.java:119)
>       at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.init(ManagedServletPipeline.java:84)
>       at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.initPipeline(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:104)
>       at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.init(GuiceFilter.java:224)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.initialize(FilterHolder.java:137)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:810)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:288)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:743)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:355)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:99)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:324)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
>       at com.citronium.fizionomizm.service.server.restserver.RESTServer.start(RESTServer.java:68)
>       at com.citronium.fizionomizm.service.Runner.main(Runner.java:19)

This exception drop while start jar from console. If start from ide, work good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realize this is old, but maybe someone else will find it useful.

In my case, this was caused by some conflicting service entries from different Jersey modules. The files in `META-INF/services/` should be merged, but mine were being overwritten.

If you use the maven shade plugin, you can use [`ServicesResourceTransformer`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#ServicesResourceTransformer) to easily merge service entries.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607220/how-can-i-merge-resource-files-in-a-maven-assembly is what helps when you use the maven-assembly-plugin the key is <containerDescriptorHandlers>
  <containerDescriptorHandler>
   <handlerName>metaInf-services</handlerName>
  </containerDescriptorHandler>