# Merge files from multiple war file

Tags: maven, maven-war-plugin

I have a main war file with maven dependencies to various war files. With the **maven-war-plugin** I am able to merge them into one, but my problem is, if files with the same name exist they will be overridden by the last one.

What I want is to merge the files with the same name.

Comment: What type of resource do you want to be merged, instead of being overridden?

Comment: html and javascript files

Answer (score 0):

This is not something done commonly with Maven. But have a look at the discussion of this SO question: [How can I merge resource files in a Maven assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607220/how-can-i-merge-resource-files-in-a-maven-assembly)